# How can I increment the value of a parameter in an object using a function?

Tags: javascript, scope, return

I want to be able to increment/change the value of a parameter inside an object. I want the value to change by accessing the value of a variable that is incrementing inside another function.

The example code below shows what I am trying to do. I would like `options.number` to increase as `i` inside `masterLoop` increases.

I know that `i` isn't defined in the scope of `function calc()`, but I can't think of a way to retrieve the value of `i` while maintaining this general code structure.

```js
(function masterLoop(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    ++i;
    masterLoopStage = i;
    console.log('Stage is: ' + i);
    masterLoop(i);
  }, 5000)
})(1);

function calc() {
  number = i; // I know i isn't defined in this scope, but I can't figure out how access the incrementing value of i inside this function  
  return number;
}

var options = {
  number: calc() // I want this vale to increase along with i inside masterLoop() 
};

setInterval(function() {
  console.log(options.number);
}, 5000);
```

Typically, in cases like this, I would try to use a `return` to retrieve a value, but I wasn't able to find a solution with that either since the incrementing value is inside a setInterval and thus its scope isn't available to the `return`.

Here is an example of that:

```js
function calc() {
  var foo = 1;
  setInterval(function() {
    var foo = foo + 1;
  }, 1000);
  return foo; // the incrementing value of foo is not available outside the scope of setIterval, so this won't work. The return also won't work inside setInterval.
}

var optionsConstant = {
  maxVolume: 10
};

var options = {
  maxVolume: optionsConstant.maxVolume + calc() // I want calc() to be able to increment along with foo in the setInterval above.
};

setInterval(function() {
  var maxVolume = options.maxVolume;
  console.log('maxVolume:   ' + maxVolume);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: It's really confusing having two different examples of what you're trying to do that are markedly different from one another, could you do just one really clear example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Separately: The `i`s (plural) in your first example's  `masterLoop` are entirely private to it, nothing outside `masterLoop` can access them. You *do* have what appears to be a global variable (at least, global to this code) which you haven't shown the declaration of (`masterLoopStage`). That would be available to `calc` in that example. But you don't have it in your second example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your second attempt, you could make `calc` an immediately invoked function expression -- providing a closure -- and in it return a function that has access to `foo`.

Then, to keep the final syntax of `options.maxVolume`, you should define that property as a getter, so that in fact it will execute some code when accessed, calling `calc()`:

```js
var calc = (function () { // create closure for foo
    var foo = 1;
    setInterval(function() {
        foo = foo + 1; // remove var!
    }, 100);
    return function calc() { // return a function
        return foo;
    }
})();

var optionsConstant = {
    maxVolume: 10
};

var options = {
    get maxVolume() { // make it a getter
        return optionsConstant.maxVolume + calc();
    }
};

setInterval(function() {
    var maxVolume = options.maxVolume;
    console.log('maxVolume:   ' + maxVolume);
}, 500);
```

Comment: @ trincot This is great! Thanks! I wasn't familiar with `get` which I'm looking forward to learning more about.

Comment: I guess you'll have found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) in the mean time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Can you declare the increment variable outside the masterloop function scope so the other functions can access it and read its' value when needed?

You'll need to make sure to re-initialize it's value when appropriate.

Comment: I edited the answer because I didn't mean true global, just expand the scope and control the init and sequencing logic.  Globals aren't always bad, right?  They just have the predisposition to being used badly very easily.

Comment: I'm still conceptually thinking through the implementation of my expanded code, but I don't think I would be able to use global variables for much of what I am trying to do because I have various functions each privately using the same paramater names. It is true that I have this masterLoop which probably could be defined globally without conflict.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to use a closure.  Here's one example:

```js
let returnI = (function masterLoop(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        ++i;
        masterLoopStage = i;
        console.log('Stage is: ' + i);
        return masterLoop(i);
    }, 5000)
})(1);

function calc() {
    number = returnI; 
    return number;
}

var options = {
    number: calc()
};

setInterval(function() {
    console.log(options.number);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Did you run the snippet and watch the output?

Comment: Yes, doesn't the author just want to return the value of "i"?

Comment: Indeed, they want `options.number` to return the value of `i`. What you see in the output is `undefined`. The other output ("Stage is: ") was already working in the OP's code, and not their question.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I saw what you mean.  Thanks for clarifying that. :)